# Simulating tbats object to give annual total and prediction interval from monthly data

Tags: r, simulation, tbats

I am trying to simulate a tbats model to give me an annual total and prediction interval when I have used monthly data to develop the tbats model. I tried the following:

```r
nsim<-10000
h<-12 #forecast ahead
sim.3<-numeric(nsim)
set.seed(1234)
for(i in seq_len(nsim))
  sim.3[i]<-sum(simulate(model3,future=TRUE, nsim=h)) 
meanagg3<-mean(sim.3); meanagg3 #should be close to model3.fc.ann
CI.3sim<-quantile(sim.3, prob=c(0.025, 0.975))
```

It returns an error message:

Error in UseMethod("simulate") :
no applicable method for 'simulate' applied to an object of class "c('tbats', 'bats')"

Is there an equivalent function in R that does? (Google search hasn't helped)